# How to round off decimals from string input and convert to int

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I would like my text entry to round off decimals and have the end result be an integer. This is what I have but it is not working. What would be the easiest way to do this? Thanks

```
decimal startMiles = Int32.Parse(txtStartMiles.Text);
startMiles = Math.Round(startMiles);
startMiles = Int32.Parse(startMiles);
```

Comment: What exactly is not working? Provide sample input and expected output

Comment: Cannot convert decimal to int etc.. I want the mileage entered in a text box lets say 56000.10 or 56000 to always be stored as an int without a decimal place

Comment: See my answer, please elt me know whether it works as you expected since from your question is not quite clear what is the issue

Comment: I edited my comment. Let me have a look at your code

Comment: Why are you using Int32.TryParse at first?

Comment: @AdamV - that was incorrect of me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
int rounded;
string input = "2.53";
decimal startMiles;

if (Decimal.TryParse(input, out startMiles))
{     
    rounded = Convert.ToInt32(startMiles);

    // here is rounded == 3
}
```

---

[Convert.ToInt32 Method (Double)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ffdk7eyz.aspx)

> Value is rounded to the nearest 32-bit signed integer. If value is halfway
>   between two whole numbers, the even number is returned; that is, 4.5
>   is converted to 4, and 5.5 is converted to 6.